# Use one virtual disk in two differents Virtual Machines

Tags: linux, postgresql, virtual-machine, vmware, esxi

I have a doubt, I'm working with a data center specifically with HP blade servers, the software installed whose control the blades is VMWare ESXi 6.0.
I've installed a virtual machine with Linux, here I have only PostgreSQL, now is running perfectly. Now I want to create a new virtual machine but using the same virtual disk, is it possible do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The virtual disk it self is just a single disk with a partition 
so it's not like create a virtual machine using the same virtual disk , the virtual disk is just the partition of your real disk or file name , you should make a multiple boot selection in your virtual disk you should remake your iso image and add the two Operating system there, use something like http://multibootusb.org/ or https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/ than recriaete your iso in usb next compile all again into a sigle iso image and choose the os in the boot menu of your VM